# Python - Shapely large shapefiles

Tags: python-2.7, gis, shapely

I am reading in a GeoJSON file that contains two simple polygon descriptions that I made and six complicated vectors from http://ryanmullins.org/blog/2015/8/18/land-area-vectors-for-geographic-combatant-commands

I can read my own 4-8 point description into Shapely Polygons. However, the more complicated descriptions from the website above give me the following error:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

jsonFile="path/to/file.json"

with open(jsonFile) as f:
    data=json.load(f)

    for feature in data['features']:
        #This is not how I'm saving the polygons, and is only for testing purposes:
        myPoly=Polygon(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
```

The error message:

```
File "/.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 229, in __init__
self._geom, self._ndim = geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)

File "/.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 508, in geos_polygon_from_py
geos_shell, ndim = geos_linearring_from_py(shell)

File "/.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 454, in geos_linearring_from_py
assert (n == 2 or n == 3)

AssertionError
```

They are read as **list**, with USAFRICOM having length 113.

Is there a way to read these very long vectors into shapely? I have tried Polygon, MultiPoint, asMultiPointIf. If not, would you be able to suggest how to simplify this vector description into something that could be read by Shapely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it gets a bit more complicated than just throwing all coordinates at Shapely in one go.

According to the [GeoJSON spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#multilinestring) and [Shapely's documentation](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#collections-of-polygons) regarding multipolygons: MultiPolygons consist of arrays of Polygons, and Polygons again consist of LinearRings which depict outer and inner areas / holes.

Here's my attempt at a MultiPolygon reader for your GeoJSON files, opening the output back in QGIS shows up correctly, let me know if you have issues.

```
import json
from shapely.geometry import mapping
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import LinearRing
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon

jsonFile = "USCENTCOM.json"
polygons = []

with open(jsonFile) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for feature in data['features']:
        for multi_polygon in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
            # collect coordinates (LinearRing coordinates) for the Polygon
            tmp_poly = [] 
            for polygon in multi_polygon:
                tmp_poly.append(polygon)
            if len(tmp_poly) > 1:
                # exterior LinearRing at [0], all following interior/"holes"
                polygons.append(Polygon(tmp_poly[0], tmp_poly[1:]))
            else:
                # there's just the exterior LinearRing
                polygons.append(Polygon(tmp_poly[0]))

# finally generate the MultiPolygon from our Polygons
mp = MultiPolygon(polygons)
# print GeoJSON string
print(json.dumps(mapping(mp)))
```